# DataAnnotationsModelBinder with MVC2 RTM

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Trying to validate models with DataAnnotations but DefaulModelBinder overrides my Required property error messages and never uses my error messages for invalid data entry. Always show 'value' is invalid for 'property name'.

In another question I saw that MVC 2 uses DataAnnotationsModelBinder but I couldn't find any class in MVC 2 binaries. I downloaded the source for MVC futures and changed some source to compile it for .Net 4.0 but although I had success to compile, it has compatability problems and doesn't work as expected.

Any help is aprreciated.

Comment: was this an upgraded project?  DefaultModelBinder exists in the System.Web.Mvc namespace and should be registered as a default binder in MVC 2.  Are you explicitly registering it in Global.asax? If so, remove that as it's already registered by default.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, changed DefaultModelBinder to DataAnnotationsModelBinder.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to go buy. Can you answer the questions above, they are still relevant.  What's in your Global.asax regarding binders? Was this an upgraded MVC1 app?

Comment: Ok. This is a fresh new project created with Visual Studio 2010. I don't make any registrations for DefaultModelBinder. All I am trying to do is use DataAnnotationsModelBinder, but it is not included with ASPNET MVC.

Comment: The DataAnnotationsModelBinder should already be enabled for a default asp.net project. You shouldn't have to do anything to make it work.  Are you trying to register the binder yourself?

Comment: No I am not. I don't think DataAnnotationsModelBinder is registered by default. It doesn't even exist in System.Web.Mvc.

Answer (score 5):

Do not try to use the DataAnnotationsModelBinder with MVC 2 RTM.  MVC 2 RTM's DefaultModelBinder already contains all of the logic that was present in the DataAnnotationsModelBinder sample.

Comment: Then why doesn't it show the error messages that I specify with [Required] attributes? It shows "x is a required field". And for the invalid types it shows "x is not a valid value for y", all standard default model binder error messages.. Shouldn't it show the error message that I write in [DataType] error message property?

Comment: It should, yes. What version of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is your project referencing?  Maybe it's a mismatch between versions

Comment: What do your declarations look like?  Can you show us a sample model (with properties) that is not behaving as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because an exception is thrown in the `DefaultModelBinder` when it tries to cast the input value to the type of the receiving model property.

You can either use `string` as type for the properties on the receiving model
or make a custom Model binder by implementing `IModelBinder` and handle the validation.

Comment: Yes, I know that and my question is exactly this, how can I use DataAnnotationsModelBinder with MVC 2 RTM. DefaultModelBinder doesn't work as expected when I use validation attributes on my model classes.