# Group by an Item and send seperate ajax request

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using .Net MVC application and jquery.I have list of OrderLines returning to the View

Structure of OrderLine will be

```
public class OrderLine
    {    
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string QuantityOrdered { get; set; }
    }
```

I have to display in the view in a table as order lines. There will be button at the bottom.
Onclicking the button, I need to group the order lines by OrderNumber and then submit each order('NOT each order line') as ajax request to the action method at a time.

Can any one tell, what is the best way to do this?

I need to post the data in the following structure

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> orderLines { get; set; }
}
```

Action Method Signature will

```
Public ActionResult Update(Order order)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `custom model binder with IModelBinder` and convert your `OrderLine` posted values into `Order` parameter to Update Action method.

**Example:**
http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/

**Best Practices when Implementing IModelBinder** [Best Practices when Implementing IModelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550520/best-practices-when-implementing-imodelbinder)