# Strange error: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know this has been asked many times but I can't solve my problem which is very funny.

My model is simple:

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "First name")]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last name")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Enter valid e-mail")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-mail is empty")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList Countries { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public virtual ActionResult Register(RegisterModel data)
        {
            if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();

                var countries =
                    this.ClientRepositoryBuilder
                        .CountryClientRepository
                        .GetAllCountries();

                data.Countries = new SelectList(countries, "Id", "CountryName");

                return
                    this.View(data);
            }
            else
            {
                return
                    this.RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.Index());
            }

        }
```

As soon as I add Countries into my model, stuff stops working and it doesn't invoke POST Action, give me an error with firebug(it's ajax post):

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Comment: Mostly likely Exception is thrown by DI in Controller's constructor.

Comment: Sounds like it can't instantiate the Ajax controller's constructor. Can you post that here?

Comment: I think it's the `Countries` property of your RegisterModel. Could your DI is trying to inject that? Comment it out (just for testing) and try to POST.

Comment: Consider having the type of `Countries` be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instead of `SelectList`

Comment: Hi thanks for responses. @JeremyCook if I use that type then it doesn't pass any value... Amount is 0 always. It doesn't invoke Post action when I include countries, but it invokes without. Very strange, just because of one SelectItem.

Comment: Check to see if it is going to the right action. If you have two actions with the same name, the request may be going to the other action. I would expect this action to have `[HttpPostAttribute]` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did a mistake with type, don't even know how I did this mistake.. So I updated model with proper type for Countries and stuff works now:

```
[Required]
public int Countries { get; set; }
```

It was a mistake due mine tiredness ;)

Answer (score 0):

Default Model binding can't deal with that object when trying to convert from information coming in request to `RegisterModel`.

Options:

- separate "incoming request model" from "view model" (as it looks like you always setting that property in controller).
- create custom model binding - check more [MSDN: The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx), or SO [When to use IModelBinder versus DefaultModelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535802/when-to-use-imodelbinder-versus-defaultmodelbinder).

If you want something like accepting list as request parameter - [Model Binding to a List MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375800/model-binding-to-a-list-mvc-4) may have an answer.