# Custom model binding using DefaultModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to understand how custom binding should work.

Assuming a simple Action of

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(CustomType parameter) {
    // do something
}
```

... and the following form data

```
{
    parameter : "mydata"
    parameter.Property1 : "something"
    parameter.Property2 : 3
}
```

... and the following, very simple custom binder

```
public class MyBinder : DefaultModelBinder {

        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

            if (bindingContext.ModelType.Equals(typeof(CustomType))) {
                string parameter = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[bindingContext.ModelName];
                object model = controllerContext.HttpContext.Cache[parameter];

                return model;
            }

            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        }

        protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) {
            // not called
            return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
        }

        protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) {
            // not called
            base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
        }

    }
```

I can see that the `BindModel` method is called. However, once I return my custom object the `BindProperty` method is never called for `Property1` and `Property2`. This makes sense, because I'm not calling `base.BindModel()`.

So my question is: How *should* `BindModel` be implemented so that it creates `CustomType` and also calls `BindModel` in the super class?

Comment: What makes you think you need a custom model binder. The data you are posting has no relationship to your model. The fact you have `parameter : "mydata"` means the first thing that happens in the model binding process is a new instance of `CustomType` type is initialized and then it tries to set the value of `CustomType = "mydata"` which of course fails (you can't set a complex object to a string). The posted data needs to be `{ Property1 : "something", Property2 : 3 }` and the `DefaultModelBinder` will initialize  a new `CustomType` and set the values of `Property1` and `Property2`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes you're right and I apologise for the contrived example. Please consider a scenario where `parameter : "mydata"` holds useful data pertinent to the creation of the object such as a key to a dictionary holding an exising object, or a serialsed representation of the object. I then want to follow up this object retrieval with the recursive property binding provided by the default binder. I hope that makes the question a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this for a while, but IIRC, you can construct your new CustomType with the properties set, rather than `return new CustomType();`

Something like:

```
return new CustomType
{
    Property1 = request.Form.Get("Property1"),
    ...
};
```

Comment: I'd much rather have the DefaultModelBinder handle the property binding rather than hard-coding each of the form keys

Answer (score 0):

I have examined the source code for [DefaultModelBinder](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs) and discovered the internal method `BindComplexElementalModel`. The desired model binding behavior can be achieved using this custom data binder.

```
public class MyBinder : DefaultModelBinder {

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

        if (bindingContext.ModelType.Equals(typeof(CustomType))) {
            // get an instance of the model using the model prefix
            string parameter = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[bindingContext.ModelName];
            object model = controllerContext.HttpContext.Cache[parameter];

            // populate the remaining model properties using reflection (yuck)
            MethodInfo bindComplexElementalModel =
                base.GetType().GetMethod("BindComplexElementalModel", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            bindComplexElementalModel.Invoke(this, new object[] { controllerContext, bindingContext, model });

            return model;
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Of course, using an internal framework method isn't a clean solution so I am leaving this question open in the hope that someone can provide a better answer.

Comment: Could you alternatively implement IModelBinder in a new custom binder?

Comment: I did wonder if that was required. Quite [a few resources](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx) recommend inheriting from `DefaultModelBinder` presumably because; if you want to maintain the same level of flexibility provided by the default binder (i.e. automatic and recursive binding of all object properties) then writing your own custom `IModelBinder` would involve re-writing a lot of that default functionality?

Comment: The comments in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535802/when-to-use-imodelbinder-versus-defaultmodelbinder) agree. I don't know the answer, but at least you got it working.